# String (date) to int (day) + int (mont) + int (year) to LocalDate

Tags: java, date

I want the user to enter a birth date, but it has to work if they put it in this pattern `dd-MM-yyyy` but also if they put it in this pattern `d-M-yyyy`. I know I have to use integers or something, but I don't know where and how. See my code below:

```
public class Student {
private int studentnr;
private String voornaam;
private String achternaam;
private LocalDate geboortedatum;
private Adres adres;

/**
 * Default Constructor maakt een student aan
 * @param studentnr
 * Studentnr wordt meegegeven in main
 * @param voornaam
 * Voornaam wordt meegegeven in main
 * @param achternaam
 * Achternaam wordt meegegeven in main
 * @param geboortedatum
 * Geboortedatum wordt meegegeven in main
 * @param adres
 * Adres wordt meegegeven in main
 */
public Student(int studentnr, String voornaam, String achternaam, String geboortedatum, Adres adres) {
    this.studentnr = studentnr;
    this.voornaam = voornaam;
    this.achternaam = achternaam;
    this.geboortedatum = LocalDate.parse(geboortedatum, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy"));
    this.adres = adres;
}
```

Comment: Just use `d-M-yyyy`, it will accept multiple digits for day and month.

Comment: or look into using a datepicker of some sort

Comment: Tip: Educate the source of your data to use standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats when exchanging date-time values. For a date-only value, that would be YYYY-MM-DD. Conveniently, the *java.time* classes use the ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generating strings. `LocalDate.parse( "2018-01-23" )`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`d-M-yyyy` pattern will work regardless of leading zeros in day and month:

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d-M-yyyy");
System.out.println(LocalDate.from(dtf.parse("1-2-2001"))); // 2001-02-01
System.out.println(LocalDate.from(dtf.parse("01-02-2001"))); // 2001-02-01
```

Comment: One may even use `d-M-y` or `d-M-u` if preferred. For birth dates of living persons it will work the same.